# Domain error when using Nelder Mead algorithm in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia

I am struggling with optimization in Julia.

I used to use Matlab but I am trying to work on Julia instead.

The following is the code I wrote.

```
using Optim

V = fill(1.0, (18,14,5))
agrid  = range(-2, stop=20, length=18)
dgrid  = range(0.01, stop=24, length=14)
#zgrid  = [0.5; 0.75; 1.0; 1.25; 1.5]
zgrid  = [0.7739832502827438; 0.8797631785217791; 1.0; 1.1366695315439874; 1.2920176239404275]
# function
function adj_utility(V,s_a,s_d,s_z,i_z,c_a,c_d)
    consumption = s_z + 1.0125*s_a + (1-0.018)*s_d - c_a - c_d - 0.05*(1-0.018)*s_d
    if consumption >= 0
        return (1/(1-2)) * ((   (consumption^0.88) * (c_d^(1-0.88))   )^(1-2))
    end
    if consumption < 0
        return -99999999
    end
end

# Optimization

    i_a = 1
    i_d = 3
    i_z = 1
    utility_adj(x) = -adj_utility(V,agrid[i_a],dgrid[i_d],zgrid[i_z],i_z,x[1],x[2])
    result1 = optimize(utility_adj, [1.0, 1.0], NelderMead())
```

If I use zgrid = [0.5; 0.75; 1.0; 1.25; 1.5], then the code works.

However, if I use zgrid  = [0.7739832502827438; 0.8797631785217791; 1.0; 1.1366695315439874; 1.2920176239404275], I got an error message "DomainError with -0.3781249999999996"

In the function, if the consumption is less than 0 then the value should be -9999999 so I am not sure why I am getting this message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `c_d` is the one with the `-0.37...` value. Replacing `c_d^(1-0.88)` with `c_d^(1)` (just as a test) makes the error go away, so that seems to be the part of the code with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising negative numbers to non-integer powers returns complex numbers, which is where your error is coming from.

```
julia> (-0.37)^(1-0.88)
ERROR: DomainError with -0.37:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_exp_domainerror(::Float64) at ./math.jl:37
 [2] ^(::Float64, ::Float64) at ./math.jl:888
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
```

You have a constraint that `consumption` must be strictly positive, but if you want `consumption` to be a real number you will need constraints that `c_d` is positive as well. You can either add this directly to your objective function as above, or you can use one of the constrained optimization [algorithms in NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/), which is available in Julia via the [NLopt package](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl).

Comment: Another common trick is to simply rescale the parameter that has a positive constraint by using a synthetic coordinate (call it `u_cd`) that is unconstrained. Then set `c_cd = exp(u_cd)`. This only works for very simple constraints, of course and the more general approach with NLopt is better, in general.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  Now I see what is the problem. May I ask you how to add constraints to make c_d to be positive inside the function?

Comment: Just change your condition on consumption to `if consumption < 0 | c_d < 0`.